# Return nested query without parent object in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested

When I query

```
db.Books.find({}, {_id: 0, "page.src": 1,"page.w": 1,"page.h": 1}).sort({"page.number": 1}).toArray()
```

It return:

```
[
    {
        "page" : [
            {
                "src" : "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.png",
                "w" : 903,
                "h" : 1300
            },
            {
                "src" : "http://xxx.xxx.xxx2.png",
                "w" : 903,
                "h" : 1300
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How do I return query without parent object like this:

```
[
    {
        "src" : "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.png",
        "w" : 903,
        "h" : 1300
    },
    {
        "src" : "http://xxx.xxx.xxx2.png",
        "w" : 903,
        "h" : 1300
    }
]
```

This result will be the input of other function

Thank you..

**EDIT**

In my machine, code from @chraidarn return like this:

```
[
    [
        {
            "src" : "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.png",
            "w" : 903,
            "h" : 1300
        },
        {
            "src" : "http://xxx.xxx.xxx2.png",
            "w" : 903,
            "h" : 1300
        }
    ]
]
```

And my function still won't running correctly. It seems pretty close. Any further idea to make it work perfectly? thank you..,

**EDIT 2**

Here's related schema if it's needed:

```
book: {
  type: String,
},
author: {
  type: String,
},
title: {
  type: String,
},
date: {
  type: Date,
},
page: {
  type: Array,
},
'page.$': {
  type: Object
},
'page.$.number': {
  type: Number
},
'page.$.src': {
  type: String
},
'page.$.w': {
  type: Number
},
'page.$.h': {
  type: Number
},
```

thank you,,

Comment: Please use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32746707/edit) to your question to show us your document; maybe there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **[`map()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/)** method on the cursor returned from the **[`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** method to return the array without the parent property page. To demonstrate this in mongo shell:

```
> var pages = db.Books.find({}, 
      {_id: 0, "page.src": 1,"page.w": 1,"page.h": 1})
  .sort({"page.number": 1})
  .map(function(doc){return doc.page});
> printjson(pages[0]); /* access the desired array result by index */
[
    {
        "src" : "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.png",
        "w" : 903,
        "h" : 1300
    },
    {
        "src" : "http://xxx.xxx.xxx2.png",
        "w" : 903,
        "h" : 1300
    }
]
>
```

Comment: Hello @chraidarn. thanks for a clue. In my machine, your code return: [
    [
        {
            "src" : "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.png",
            "w" : 903,
            "h" : 1300
        },
        {
            "src" : "http://xxx.xxx.xxx2.png",
            "w" : 903,
            "h" : 1300
        }
    ]
]. And my function still won't running correctly. It seems pretty close. Any further idea to make it work perfectly? thank you..

Comment: @KarinaL you should edit your question, not that answer.

Comment: @KarinaL I have edited my answer, you can access the desired array using the index 0.

Comment: @chridam thank you very much, it's work perfectly now. I won't forget your help, thank you...

Answer (score 0):

```
*One more option, you can use aggregation with map* 

> db.Books.aggregate([{$unwind:"$page"},{$project:{_id:0,"page":1}}]).map(function(doc){return doc.page}
)

**Result**

[
        {
                "src" : "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.png",
                "w" : 903,
                "h" : 1300
        },
        {
                "src" : "http://xxx.xxx.xxx2.png",
                "w" : 903,
                "h" : 1300
        }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using aggregation framework like this

```
db.Books.aggregate( {$project: {"src" : "$page.src", "w": "$page.w", "h": "$page.h", _id: 0}} )
```

Answer (score 0):

No filter

```
db.Books.distinct("page")
```

filter

```
db.Books.distinct("page", { "page": 1 })
```